# #error directive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Does the #error directive work in Microsoft Visual C++? Is, so what is the syntax. I found this sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if MyVAL != 2
#error MyVAL must be defined to 2
#endif
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

And I get the error:

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  MyVAL must be defined to 2
```

From what I have seen, usual syntax is as seen above, but Windows Visual Studios 2010, does not like this? Is there a way to implement this in MSVS 2010. Thank you!

Comment: What is `MyVAL` ? Is it a environment variable (or) pre-processor directive passed to the build environment ? If not, I think you should with MyVAL value being 2.

Comment: Oh I understand. The fact that it shows my error message as I typed it means that it is working properly. Am I understanding that correctly? If I am I feel really dumb now!

Comment: Yes. The [`#error` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk.aspx) emits the compiler error [C1189](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0tzt8e0.aspx) with the text that you specify. The fact that you got that error shows that the macro expression `MyVAL != 2` evaluated to being true, and therefore the error was emitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is totally a dumb question. As the comments indicate, the error I received is exactly what I was supposed to.

Comment: "There are no dumb questions..." Actually there are dumb questions, but this most certainly isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks! I just hope that now someone else can avoid spending far too much time on this non-error error!